# fix looping error in block with foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, foreach, webmatrix

I have some ASP.NET code to fetch from my database. The code is as follows:

```
@{ //begin block

var appDb = Database.Open("apps");
var msg = "hi";
Layout = "~/Header.cshtml";
var queryStr = "SELECT * FROM Apps WHERE appid = '" + @Request.QueryString["id"] + "'";
foreach (var query in appDb.Query(queryStr)) { //begin foreach
    <img src="@query.pictureUrl" /><br>
    <h2 style="display:  inline;"></h2> <h3 style="display: inline;">by </h3>
   <p>

       </p>
} // end foreach
} // end block
```

However, WebMatrix says that the //end foreach is the end of the block, not the end of the foreach. It also comes up with this error:

```
"}" expected at line 
<end of file, i'm only copying the errored block but for me it's line 19>
 at column 4
```

So I fix the error, and guess what? It comes up AGAIN. Fix again, appear again and so on.

How do I fix the error

Comment: A little bit off topic, but you should find some information about Sql Injection

Comment: Comment out stuff to narrow down the possible causes.

Comment: @Rudis SQL Injection is _never_ off topic. Just think about all those Little Bobby Tables out there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor is fussy about open HTML tags being matched with closing ones. The error message is not always that helpful, but your issue is cause by the `<br>`tag not being closed. All you need to do is add a '/' to it:

```
@{ 
var appDb = Database.Open("apps");
var msg = "hi";
Layout = "~/Header.cshtml";
var queryStr = "SELECT * FROM Apps WHERE appid = @0";
foreach (var query in appDb.Query(queryStr, Request.QueryString["id"])) { 
    <img src="@query.pictureUrl" /><br />
    <h2 style="display:  inline;"></h2> 
    <h3 style="display: inline;">by </h3>

    <p></p>
    } 
}
```

I have also addressed the rightful concern from Rudis about SQL Injection and replaced your string concatenation with a parameter. Incidentally, if you only expect to get one row of data as a result of your query, you should use QuerySingle instead of Query:

```
@{ 
    var appDb = Database.Open("apps");
    var msg = "hi";
    Layout = "~/Header.cshtml";
    var queryStr = "SELECT * FROM Apps WHERE appid = @0";
    var record = appDb.QuerySingle(queryStr, Request.QueryString["id"]); 
    if(record != null){
        <img src="@record.pictureUrl" /><br />
        <h2 style="display:  inline;"></h2> 
        <h3 style="display: inline;">by </h3>

        <p></p>
    } 
}
```

You can learn a lot more about managing data within Web Pages here: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data